# I am looking for a method for solving this differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fln2w.png)While experimenting with diodes I have come across the following differential equation:

Let $ a_1 , a_2 , a_3, a_4,$ and   $K$ be real numbers greater than zero.

$K = a_1 y' + a_2 y   +  a_3 ln(a_4y')$

$y(0)=0$

Does anyone have any advice for how to tackle that equation? That natural log is really tripping me up.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Using the implicit function theorem, you could locally express the above differential equation in standard form i.e. $y' = f(t, y)$ then use numerical methods to study the solution. I don't think there is any easy way to compute a closed form solution for the above differential equation.

Comment: If $a_3$ is small compared to $a_1,a_2$, and $K,$ then you could set it equal to zero and find an approximate solution.

Comment: $a_3$ is a little under 1/4, but $a_4$ is to the power of 10.

Comment: This is what I've done so far... 
I have decided to treat Q' like an independent variable and Q as a dependent variable. I chose some reasonable values for all the constants and plotted it.

Comment: I'm not working on producing some regressions for different parts of the plot. There is a linear part and a exponential decay-type part. I am hoping to get some kinda of decent expression for y.

Comment: Could you give me (for a test) a set of values of the constants ?

Comment: $K=5, a_1=100, a_2=1000, a_3=24, a_4= 70000000000$

Answer (score 0):

Considering the equation $$K = a_1 y' + a_2 y   +  a_3 \log(a_4y')$$ where $y$ is a function of $x$.

First, solve for $y'$; the solution is given in terms of Lambert function 
$$y'=\frac{{a_3} }{{a_1}}\,\,W\left(\frac{{a_1} }{{a_3} {a_4}}e^{\frac{K-a_2 y}{{a_3}}}\right)=\frac 1{x'}$$ Now, integrate with respect to $y$ (this is not the most funny part, but a CAS did it) and get $$x+C =\frac {a_1}{a_2}\left(\frac 1z-\log(z) \right)\qquad \text{with}\qquad z=W\left(\frac{{a_1} }{{a_3} {a_4}}e^{\frac{K-a_2 y}{{a_3}}}\right)$$

Comment: From there, is it possible to reorder those last two expressions so that they give you a function of y? (Not familiar with the Lambert function)

Comment: @Ben. It is a fascinating function with many applications in all areas. Have a look at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function . You will not be able to express $y$ as a function of $x$.

Comment: I wrote some constants down in the other sub thread. And I also just uploaded an image of the graph I was talking about. Q' vs Q